# Reuse screen to edit

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a screen with date field and some with boxes, I need to fill them to reautify the screen for editing, the screen serves to register and edit, however I am not able to pass the data to the combobox fields. The data returned by the bank is the id of the option.

Page code:

```
    <ion-grid  *ngFor="let editar of lista_despesa_ed">

        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-6 class="sem-espaco">
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label floating>Data</ion-label>
              <ion-datetime class="input-color" displayFormat="DD MM YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="data"></ion-datetime>
            </ion-item>
            <h6 *ngIf="errorData" class="error"> {{messageData}}</h6>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-12 class="sem-espaco">
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Centro de Custo</ion-label>
                <ion-select (ionChange)="resetCusto()" [(ngModel)]="custo" class="input-color">
                  <ion-option *ngFor="let custo of lista_centroCusto" [selected]="editar.IDCentroCusto" value="{{custo.Chave}}">{{custo.Valor}}
                  </ion-option> //The error occurs here
                </ion-select>
              </ion-item>
              <h6 *ngIf="errorCusto" class="error"> {{messageCusto}}</h6>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
```

Typescript file:

```
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    if (this.global.acao === "I") {
      this.carregaCB();
    } else if (this.global.acao === "E") {
      this.carregaCB();
      this.AprovacaoProvider.listaDetalhe().then((data) => {
        this.lista_despesa_ed = data;
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since your reputation is higher than 15 you can upvote questions and answers. Feel free to review *[what upvoting is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)* and *whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `[(ngModel)]` in that combobox and `custo` is the property from the component that is bounded to it, you just need to assign the value of the already selected option to the `custo` property in your component file:

```
this.custo = editar.IDCentroCusto; // Not sure if this is the right property
```

And then in the view:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="custo" class="input-color">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let custo of lista_centroCusto" [value]="custo.Chave">{{custo.Valor}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Please notice that I'd also suggest to use property binding for `value` (instead of string interpolation) like this: `[value]="custo.Chave"`.